# Flutter Bluetooth Devices as Stream?

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth

happy new year,

I am currently building a small application that should execute a given function if bluetooth gets turned off and on and if bluetooth connects/disconnects from a device. But I cant get the second part to work. I have set all permissions in manifest and apple equivalent. I am using flutterBlue (an instance of that).

flutterBlue.state.listen((event) {...}); does work but
flutterBlue.connectedDevices.asStream().listen((event) {...}) not.
If I debug not one event is happening even though I connected a bt device.

What do I need to use/do to get the functionality I want?

Comment: so i assume that you used `flutterBlue.connectedDevices.asStream().listen(print);` and then connected / disconnected one or more devices and nothing appeared on the logs?

Comment: I used flutterBlue.connectedDevices.asStream().listen((event) {...} and in ... an own function which basically just prints strings and nothing happened when connecting or disconnecting devices

Answer (score 0):

Import this package:

```
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart' as blueB;
```

Add this new variable:

```
initState(){
flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));
flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
  for (blueB.ScanResult r in results) {
    print('Device ${r.device.name} found!');
  }
});
}

blueB.FlutterBlue flutterBlue = blueB.FlutterBlue.instance;
```